# Getting TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects error when saving the result dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to store the predictions, best params, and performance scores for each shuffle in the main dictionary.

When I attempt to save the dictionary object at the end of each shuffle loop,
the error message `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects` raises.

I have used both `json.dump(dictObj, open(fileName + ".json", 'w'))` and `pickle.dump(finalObj, open(outputFile + ".pck", 'wb'))` methods.

Unluckily, both of them gave the same error.

Even I tried the `copy` module with `copy.deepcopy()` function before saving it.

Is there someone who had the same error and fixed it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure `dictObj` is a `dict` object?

Comment: Yes, here is the definition of it: finalObj = {x:{} for x in nGramTypes}